# Mostrar renglon flotando drag drop cxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, drag-and-drop

Hola mi problema es que deseo que al hacer "drag&drop" en un cxGrid (DevExpress), específicamente DBTableView, se muestre el renglon flotando o algún texto.

Creo que solo es ajustar las propiedades, pero no he podido hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Mario, faltan detalles a tu pregunta para que los demás usuarios podamos entender lo que necesitas. Personalmente no que queda claro a qué te refieres uando hablas de un "renglón flotante", por ejemplo.

Comment: Hola, buenos días. No encuentro la manera de como explicar que al hacer el Drag o arrastre, se simule que el renglon que tengo seleccionado se despega del grid y lo estoy arrastrando. Es decir que se vea una copia del renglon seleccionado pero ahora flotando sobre el grid. En lugar de solo ver el texto. No sé si logré explicarme un poco mejor...

Answer (score 1):

Las cxGrid de las DevExpress poseen propiedades para modificar elementos a la hora de realizar el **Drag&Drop**, como comentas.
En las propiedades del DBTableView tienes la propiedad `OptionsBehavior/DragDropText` para permitir que el texto que se arrastra, se muestre en pantalla durante la operacion.

Por defecto se muestra el valor, si necesitas modificar el texto que se visualiza, debes utilizar el evento `OnGetDragDropText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the prpoperties: `OptionsBehavior/DragDropText` to True and `OptionsBehavior/DragFocusing` to dfDragDrop

I have tried this change and the result is like this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]